# How can setting smtp email on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, email, web, smtp, setting

How to smtp setting on wordpress,actually http://snvenkataraman.com/ this website move hosting aws server.Use by plugin-contact form 7 and WP Mail SMTP plugin,
contact form not working?
[image]
![][2]
my email configuration is :

From Email : abc@gmail.com,
From Name : abc

Mailer:

Return Path:
SMTP Options

SMTP Host:smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Port:25
Encryption:
Authentication:
Username:abc@gmail.com
Password:******
Send a Test Email: abc@gmail.com

Comment: When you send test mail via WP Mail SMTP Plugin, did you getting that mail in your inbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can send mail Through Phpmailer. this is the code. Just add Phpmailer file in root directory.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
include_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$first = @$_POST['name'];
$last = @$_POST['last'];
$email = @$_POST['email'];
ob_start();
?>
<table width="361" align="center" style="border-bottom:solid #848484 thin; border-left:solid #848484 thin; border-top:solid #848484 thin; border-right:solid #848484 thin;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" style="border-bottom:solid #848484 thin; border-left:solid #848484 thin; border-top:solid #84848``4 thin; border-right:solid #848484 thin;">Contact Form</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td width="21" style="border-bottom:solid #848484 thin; border-left:solid #848484 thin; border-top:solid #848484 thin; border-right:solid #848484 thin;"><span class="style3">First Name</span></td>
        <td width="39" style="border-bottom:solid #848484 thin; border-left:solid #848484 thin; border-top:solid #848484 thin; border-right:solid #848484 thin;"><span class="style3"><?php echo $first; ?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ($last == 0) { ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="21" style="border-bottom:solid #848484 thin; border-left:solid #848484 thin; border-top:solid #848484 thin; border-right:solid #848484 thin;"><span class="style3">Last Name</span></td>
            <td width="39" style="border-bottom:solid #848484 thin; border-left:solid #848484 thin; border-top:solid #848484 thin; border-right:solid #848484 thin;"><span class="style3"><?php echo $last; ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="21" style="border-bottom:solid #848484 thin; border-left:solid #848484 thin; border-top:solid #848484 thin; border-right:solid #848484 thin;"><span class="style3">E-Mail</span></td>
        <td width="39" style="border-bottom:solid #848484 thin; border-left:solid #848484 thin; border-top:solid #848484 thin; border-right:solid #848484 thin;"><span class="style3"><?php echo $email; ?></span></td>
    </tr>       
</table>
<?php
$message = ob_get_clean();
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SetFrom('do-not-reply@example.com', 'Example');
$mail->AddAddress('yts.sachin@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = "Call Back Request From example.com";
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

if ($mail->Send())
    echo $mail = "Mail Sent!";
else
    echo $mail = "There is an error while sending a mail:" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
?>
```